# Expressjs doesn't destroy session

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express

I have an Backbone View which sends an Ajax call to the server to remove a session.

On the server following event is triggered:

```
app.delete('/session', function(req, res) {
    if (req.session) {
        req.session.destroy(function() {
            res.clearCookie('connect.sid', { path: '/' });
            res.send('removed session', 200);
        });
    } else {
        res.send('no session assigned', 500);
    }
});
```

The weird about this is that I can press the logout button multiple times without getting a HTTP 500 error code. Also chromium shows me that a cookie still exists.

What is going wrong?

Regards

**EDIT**:

I found out that this isn't directly a session issue but a cookie one.
I added res.clearCookie to the route. Unfortunatly the behaviour (cookie, session keep alive) didn't change

**EDIT2**:
I now gave res.clearCookie some parameters => res.clearCookie('connect.sid', { path: '/' });
Now at least the cookie is gone in the browser. But the session seems to be still available.
Or at least I can call the logout route how often I want even req.session should be false

**EDIT3:**
I now removed all sessions out of redis and restarted everything (redis, node, browser).
Than I have logged in again and logged out. This works so far but when I relaod the page with F5 I get a new session. WHY?

Comment: What happens if you do `delete req.session;`

Comment: This doesn't affect the session at least not to the next request because you just locally remove the variable not the redis key. req.session.destroy removes this too. But see the update

Comment: you don't necessarily have to clear the cookie, connect will give you a new session in the event of one that doesn't exist, perhaps that's what you're perceiving as the same session?

Comment: Yep, this should be it. But how does authentication work if I always have a session?

Comment: @kyogron You typically store a flag in the session as to whether it's been authenticated yet or not.

Comment: @JohnnyHK a secret key or just something like authenticated: true?

Comment: @kyogron Just a simple flag like `authenticated: true`

Comment: @JohnnyHK I summarized everything for to an answer.

Comment: yeah you place a user id in the session etc, even unauthenticated users may still have say for example shopping cart items in their session

Comment: I found out that for destroying a session I have to `req.session.destry()`, but where is the "official" documentation/reference about that? I searched in expressjs documentation and nodejs HTTP documentation but didn't find anything...

Comment: @niconic http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/session.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To concentrate all comments together I have written an answer:

Because express always creates a session and a cookie for a client we have to take a different approach than just to check if there is a session.

This parts handles logins

```
app.post('/session', function(req, res) {
    User.findOne({ username: req.body.username })
        .select('salt') // my mongoose schema doesn't fetches salt
        .select('password') // and password by default
        .exec(function(err, user) {
            if (err || user === null) throw err; // awful error handling here
            // mongoose schema methods which checks if the sent credentials
            // are equal to the hashed password (allows callback)
            user.hasEqualPassword(req.body.password, function(hasEqualPassword) {
                if (hasEqualPassword) {
                    // if the password matches we do this:
                    req.session.authenticated = true; // flag the session, all logged-in check now check if authenticated is true (this is required for the secured-area-check-middleware)
                    req.session.user = user; // this is optionally. I have done this because I want to have the user credentials available
                    // another benefit of storing the user instance in the session is
                    // that we can gain from the speed of redis. If the user logs out we would have to save the user instance in the session (didn't tried this)
                    res.send(200); // sent the client that everything gone ok
                } else {
                    res.send("wrong password", 500); // tells the client that the password was wrong (on production sys you want to hide what gone wronge)
                }
            });
        });
});
```

That was the login part lets go to the logout:

```
app.delete('/session', function(req, res) {
    // here is our security check
    // if you use a isAuthenticated-middleware you could make this shorter
    if (req.session.authenticated) {
        // this destroys the current session (not really necessary because you get a new one
        req.session.destroy(function() {
            // if you don't want destroy the whole session, because you anyway get a new one you also could just change the flags and remove the private informations
            // req.session.user.save(callback(err, user)) // didn't checked this
            //delete req.session.user;  // remove credentials
            //req.session.authenticated = false; // set flag
            //res.clearCookie('connect.sid', { path: '/' }); // see comments above                res.send('removed session', 200); // tell the client everything went well
        });
    } else {
        res.send('cant remove public session', 500); // public sessions don't containt sensible information so we leave them
    }
});
```

Hope this helps