# Node session not saving correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, session

I'm seeing something very odd with node sessions. I'm using [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session) and [connect-mongo](https://github.com/jdesboeufs/connect-mongo) to save the session.

My session setup is as follows (all requests are over https):

```
var session = require('express-session');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo/es5')(session);

var sess = {};

app.use(session({
    secret: 'xxxx',
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: new MongoStore({
        mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection,
        ttl: 60 * 30 // haf hour
    }),
    cookie: { secure: true }
}));
```

I have a route that creates an image with node canvas:

```
app.get('/api/canvas', function(req, res) {

    sess = req.session;

    console.log('in canvas and sess is ', sess);

    // create image stuff
});
```

Elsewhere in the app, you can set stuff like background colors. I then have a route to clear these:

```
app.get('/api/clear', function(req, res) {

    sess = req.session;

    if (sess.colors) {
        delete sess.colors;
    }

    sess.save(function(err) {
        console.log('saved sess is now ', sess);
        // session saved
        helper.sendJsonResponse(req, res, 200, {});
    })
});
```

`helper.sendJsonResponse()` just responds with a **200** HTTP code and an empty body.

You can see I use a callback for the `session.save()` as I only want to respond to the request when I KNOW the session has been edited and saved.

However, this doesn't always work. If I set colors in the session, then clear them (by calling the 'api/clear' route), then call the route to create the image (by calling 'api/canvas' route), the session on the 'api/canvas' route session sometimes still has the colors set.

This seems to be the case only if I do it quickly. If I wait a few seconds, the colors are cleared for the 'api/canvas' route.

Note: I do not allow calls to these routes at the same time - I use promises and have a spinner in the UI which covers the whole screen until requests fully complete.

When the this happens, the logs look like:

```
saved sess is now  { cookie: 
   { path: '/',
     _expires: null,
     originalMaxAge: null,
     httpOnly: true },
  canvasHeight: 500,
  canvasWidth: 591 
}
```

And when I make request to 'api/canvas':

```
in canvas and sess is  { cookie: 
   { path: '/',
     _expires: null,
     originalMaxAge: null,
     httpOnly: true },
  canvasHeight: 500,
  canvasWidth: 591,
  colors: 
   { 
      color1: 'red',
      color2: 'green'
    } 
}
```

so you can see, colors property is still set. This happens about 50% of the time. The rest of the time, on the second request the colors property has been deleted.

What could possibly be going wrong? Am I misunderstanding how sessions work?

**EDIT**

This gets ever odder. If I chain the calls in the UI, that is called the 'api/clear' route then in the Promise then() method, call the 'api/canvas' route, it ALWAYS works. If I call to make the requests individually, the results are completely random - sometimes the session will get updated, sometimes it won't.

I checked `req.sessionID` and it's always the same for the different requests.

**EDIT**
Using the [regenerate method](https://github.com/expressjs/session#sessionregeneratecallback) works correctly, but isn't ideal as I lose everything in the session.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the saving part of 'session' code itself - with and without `resave` param set to `false`?

Comment: you mean the save method within the express-session package?

Comment: Yes. You can trace the whole thing actually, starting from your code. The key point is to understand when exactly the session is fetched and stored.

Comment: ill try that and get back to you, thanks

Comment: Can you put the code that you are using to call those functions?

Comment: 'saveUninitialized' is set to false. try making this true. Also explcitly set resave:false. If session is not modified it will not save.

Comment: Why are you keep `sess` in a global variable? It's bad practice.

Comment: Think this is a duplication of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11575807/expressjs-doesnt-destroy-session

Comment: @Shawyeok dont think its a global variable. Arent global variable declared without 'var'?

Comment: @damianfabian been really busy with work, will update question when i get a chance with frontend calls

Comment: @DrEarnest will try that when i get a chance, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The delete operator deletes only a reference, never an object itself. If it did delete the object itself, other remaining references would be dangling, like a C++ delete. (And accessing one of them would cause a crash. To make them all turn null would mean having extra work when deleting or extra memory for each object.)

Since Javascript is garbage collected, you don't need to delete objects themselves - they will be removed when there is no way to refer to them anymore.

It can be useful to delete references to an object if you are finished with them, because this gives the garbage collector more information about what is able to be reclaimed. If references remain to a large object, this can cause it to be unreclaimed - even if the rest of your program doesn't actually use that object.

**Reference:**http://jennifermann.ghost.io/deleting-objects-in-javascript/

Hope this helps.

Comment: did you try assigning colors = null ?