# How to completely destroy/clear current session in express when using filestore

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express

Here is my logout code in my node.js:

```js
    export function logout(req, res) {
       var logoutUrl = authServer + '/1.0/Account/Logout';
       var thisReq = req;
       var thisRes = res;
       request({
         method: 'GET',
         url : logoutUrl
       },
        function (error, response, body) {
         thisReq.session.destroy();
         thisReq.session.user = null;
         thisReq.session = null;
         thisRes.clearCookie('connect.sid', { path: '/' });
      }).pipe(res);
   }
```

After above code is executed, in another route file, I am checking this..

```
function isAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if (req.session.user) {
    console.log('Session user FOUND_______________________________________');
    return next();
  } 
  console.log('No Session user FOUND!_______________________________________');

  return res.send(401, 'No current user found in the session');
}
```

Although after executing logout, I still see 'Session user Found....' message being logged to console.

And here is how I am configuring the express session file store..

```
var fileStoreOptions = {};
  app.use(session({
    store: new FileStore(fileStoreOptions),
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
  }));
```

Comment: I did look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11575807/expressjs-doesnt-destroy-session) question but did not help me resolving issue that I explained in my question above.

Comment: Am I missing something...where in the heck do you define **req** via your client?

Comment: @LostJon - I modified my question - would it work? sorry, I am newbie to all this. Thanks!

Comment: you should be able to ensure that it was killed by adding some logging in the call back of `req.session.destroy()`. The other lines after the destroy are unnecessary. you can effectively mock the session destroy by setting `req.session = {}` , but you shouldnt need to do that.